# Why does a "Viking with hat with horn" appears in php_info() output?

Tags: php, apache

A strange image appeared in the top right when running [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/function.phpinfo.php)  Normally there was the PHP logo.

What is going on? How can I avoid this?

My code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

[image]

Comment: It's April Fools day.

Comment: It's probably a joke from April 1. But it should be avoided. Joke like this on servers is not a good idea.

Comment: I almost rebuild my php because of this image.

Comment: http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php

Comment: Funny, but off-topic as it's not related to programming/coding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an undocumented(?) build in [Easter Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29).

> An Easter egg is an intentional inside joke, hidden message, or feature in an interactive work such as a computer program, video game or DVD menu screen.

In the [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71c19800258ee3a9548af9a5e64ab0a62d1b1d8e/ext/standard/info.c#L851) you can find those lines:

```
if (ta && (ta->tm_mon==3) && (ta->tm_mday==1)) {
    php_info_print(PHP_EGG_LOGO_DATA_URI "\" alt=\"PHP logo\" /></a>");
} else {
    php_info_print(PHP_LOGO_DATA_URI "\" alt=\"PHP logo\" /></a>");
}
```

On the first day of the fourth month (1th of April) it does "something special" to the logo on the `php_info()`. ;-)

To avoid those "jokes" [configure PHP with `expose_php=off`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php).

A nice collection of some historic PHP Easter Eggs logos can be found on http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php

[image: Historic PHP Easter Eggs logos]

Comment: Thanks powtac! You will help many desperate people thinking that the server has been hacked.

Comment: I have "expose_php=Off" on my php.ini. But this "joke" keeps appearing.

Comment: @RodrigoGomes reload server?

Comment: Yes, and still appearing. PHP Version: 5.6.19

Comment: @RodrigoGomes Same for me, logo still shows up! expose_php is off and my PHP version is 5.6.19! The documentation states that `... also affected the output of phpinfo(), as when disabled, the PHP logo and credits information would not be displayed.` Looks like you found a PHP bug, congratulations!

Comment: this will scare so many people. lol
Well, thanks for you help!

Comment: Will you open a bug report regarding the display of the logo? Else I will do it soon.

Comment: If you want, you can open! :)

Comment: @powtac: The documentation states also: `Note:
Since PHP 5.5.0 these guids and the php_logo_guid() function have been removed from PHP [....] Similarly, turning expose_php off will not affect seeing the PHP logo in phpinfo().` Does this mean that expose_php=off will not affect the logo anymore?

Comment: I just found the commit where expose_php check for logo was removed: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/ee6540ad092ce2f2aedb2e677b292b58acdca9be